# How to get specific MYSLQ results that matches multiple categories

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my MySQL one for the Books information and another table for the Books categories. Example:

**books Table**

```
id           title        
===         =========       
1         Space Opera          
2         Mars Attack         
3         Mortal               
4         Adventure Ride
```

**book_category Table**

```
id     book_id     category_id
===    =========    =========
1         10            2
2         24            3 
3         10            8
4         7             1
```

If need a list of all books with their information from one category the query below will work fine

```
SELECT b.id, b.title  
    FROM books b
    LEFT JOIN book_category c ON c.book_id=b.id
    WHERE c.category_id = 2
```

However, my difficulty is that I don't know how to get a list of books that matches multiple categories (and ignoring all the other books that don't match 100% in all of those categories).

The idea is to have for example a list of books that are Sci-Fi and Mystery and Adventure, and ignoring all the other books that don't match exactly with this criteria.

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm providing minimal reproducible examples on my post...

Comment: *I'm providing minimal reproducible examples on my post...* No. It must contain CREATE TABLE for all tables, INSERT INTO for all tables, desired result for this data.

Comment: And note that, while harmless, book_category.id is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT b.id, b.title  
FROM books b
INNER JOIN book_category c ON c.book_id=b.id
WHERE c.category_id IN (2, 8)  -- categories IDs list
GROUP BY b.id, b.title  
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.category_id) = 2 -- the amount of categories in the list
```

If the fields pair `book_category (book_id, category_id)` is unique (set by UNIQUE index) then DISTINCT in HAVING is excess.